# $scope после конкатинации

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Хочу минимизировать код

```
 if($scope.mUnit === 'GC'){
                                pay.amountMin = new BigNumber(pay.amountMin).plus(metersAmount).toFixed(2);
                            }
if($scope.mUnit === 'KW'){
                                pay.amountMin = new BigNumber($scope.KW).times(item.difference).times(meters.Tariff).toFixed(2);
                            }
                            if($scope.mUnit === 'MW'){
                                pay.amountMin = new BigNumber($scope.MW).times(item.difference).times(meters.Tariff).toFixed(2);
                            }
                            if($scope.mUnit === 'GJ'){
                                pay.amountMin = new BigNumber($scope.GJ).times(item.difference).times(meters.Tariff).toFixed(2);
                            }
```

на такой

```
 if($scope.mUnit === 'GC'){
                            pay.amountMin = new BigNumber(pay.amountMin).plus(metersAmount).toFixed(2);
                        }else{
                            pay.amountMin = new BigNumber($scope.chosenUnit).times(item.difference).times(meters.Tariff).toFixed(2);
                        }
```

Пытаюсь подставить $scope.chosenUnit значение которое передается, таким образом

```
 $scope.mUnit = meterUnit;
$scope.chosenUnit = '$scope.' + $scope.mUnit;
```

Юнит это KW,MW,GJ, их значение ниже. Но получается что $scope.chosenUnit становится строкой и скрипт не срабатывает как нужно. Скоуп по идее это же обьект? как его перевести в обьект или возможно есть другой вариант решения ?
Мне в итоге нужно что бы на месте $scope.chosenUnit было одно из (смотря что получаю)

```
$scope.KW = 0.0008598;
$scope.MW = 0.8598;
$scope.GJ = 0.239;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> '$scope.' + $scope.mUnit;
> ```

```
$scope[$scope.mUnit];
```

Или так (хотя в данном случае не стоит):

```
$scope.$eval($scope.mUnit);
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можете обьяснить разницу между первым и вторым вариантом и почему вторым не стоит пользоваться в данном случае?

Comment: @Maxim, первый берёт просто поле объекта, а второй заставляет ангуляр полностью распарсить строку и вычислить соответствующее значение на скоупе. Во втором случае можно скармливать глубокую вложенность, а так же различные выражения.

Comment: Большое спасибо!